# Seeking shapefile of unincorporated areas (US)?

Tags: usa, geospatial, census

I've been working with TIGER/Line [shapefiles of CDPs/towns/cities](https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2016&layergroup=Places), and want to fill in the empty areas between these places with shapes of those unincorporated areas well. So far, I've been unable to find shapefiles of the unincorporated areas at a national scale. Are these available to download in one dataset?

Comment: This is a question which I think would be more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. I don't have enough rep to move it -- would you be able to? If not, I can just delete and re-post.

Comment: you can use the erase(arcmap)/difference(qgis) geoprocessing tool to remove the city boundary shapes from a national county shapefile

Answer (score 2):

Having worked with Census Bureau shapefiles for nearly seven years, I'm almost certain this isn't available by default. That said, the Census Bureau does provide Shapefiles of municipality boundaries.

You **might** be able to use something like QGis to load a shape file of all municipalities, then select the bounding area, and perform an inverse selection command using the differences geoprocessing tool, which would draw a polygon filling in anywhere inside the bounding box that doesn't already have spatial layers.

Comment: R's spatial packages can be powerful tools if you go this route.i used a similar technique to punch out rural areas in counties by subtracting census "places."